# @RunWith(JUnit4.class) + GrpcCleanupRule vs @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) + @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a problem with testing GRpcService and getting beans from my SpringContext.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        Application.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MainFlowTest3 {
    
    @Rule
    public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

    @Autowired
    private RouteService routeService;
    @Autowired
    private RouteRequestService routeRequestService;
    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;
  
}
```

When I use **@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)** I have problems with testing grpc.
My exception is

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract delegate()Lio/grpc/ServerBuilder; of abstract class io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder. 
...
```

I found an answer. I was because I should use **@RunWith(JUnit4.class)**.
But when I use it all my Autowired beans are **null**.

How can I combine both logics in my test? I need both @Autowired beans and testing grpc service in one test.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a different Junit4 runner you can do the following which will enable the same functionality as the JUnit4 Runner,

```
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

Can see the JavaDoc here,

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html

A concrete example is available here.

http://eddumelendez.github.io/blog/2015/08/01/spring-4-2-0-springclassrule-and-springmethodrule/

In your case you'll need to use the rule chain as you have multiple rules,

```
 @Rule
        public RuleChain chain= RuleChain
                               .outerRule(new SpringMethodRule())
                               .around(new GrpcCleanupRule());
```

Another option would be to try to move to JUnit5 as it supports multiple "rules"/Runners now extensions much more elgantly, or you could write an integration test to spin up the application and apply a certain profile to the running application to enable stubbed beans/mock integration etc. to allow more blackbox testing of the application to avoid needing the rules as Rules are very limiting in Junit4

Comment: I've already tried it. But theese rules somehow clash with 
`@Rule public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();`

And I get the same exception as I in my post.

Comment: ah sorry missed that, see the updated example